# Can not access Virtual Slide methods in SwiperJs using Angular

Tags: angular, swiper.js

I'm using [SwiperJs](https://swiperjs.com/angular#getting-started) `v6.6.1` to create a slider in my Angular 12 app.

Here is my Angular component

```
import SwiperCore, {
  Pagination,
  Navigation,
  EffectCoverflow,
} from 'swiper/core';
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, ViewChild, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { SwiperComponent } from 'swiper/angular';

SwiperCore.use([Pagination, Navigation, EffectCoverflow]);

declare var $: any;
@Component({
  selector: 'app-eg-image',
  templateUrl: './eg-image.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./eg-image.component.scss'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})
export class EgImageComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('swiperRef', { static: false }) sliderRef?: SwiperComponent;

  public thumbsSwiper: any;
  public swiper: any;
  public slides = [
    'https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg',
    'https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg',
    'https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-3.jpg',
    'https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-4.jpg',
    'https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-5.jpg',
    'https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-6.jpg',
    'https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-7.jpg',
    'https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg',
  ];
  public activeImage: any = this.slides[0];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.swiper = {
      autoHeight: 'true',
      effect: 'coverflow',
      spaceBetween: 50,
      grabCursor: 'true',
      centeredSlides: 'true',
      slidesPerView: 'auto',
      coverflowEffect: {
        rotate: 50,
        stretch: 0,
        depth: 100,
        modifier: 1,
        slideShadows: true,
      },
      pagination: {
        dynamicBullets: true,
        el: '.swiper-pagination',
        type: 'fraction',
      },
      navigation: true,
    };

    $('#bg-image').css(
      'background-image',
      'url(https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-10.jpg)'
    );
  }

  onSlideChange(event: any) {
    this.activeImage = this.slides[event.realIndex];
    $('#bg-image').css('background-image', 'url(' + this.activeImage + ')');
  }

  onSlideEnd(event: any) {
    console.log('onSlideEnd', event);
    this.appendSlides();
  }

  appendSlides() {
    this.sliderRef!.swiperRef.appendSlide([
      `<div class="swiper-slide"><img class="swiper-slide1" src="${this.slides[0]}" /></div>`,
    ]);
  }

  setThumbsSwiper(swiper: any) {
    this.thumbsSwiper = swiper;
  }
}
```

and here is my HTML code,

```
<div class="swiper-container">
  <div id="bg-image"></div>
  <div class="swiper-wrapper">
    <swiper
      [config]="swiper"
      (slideChange)="onSlideChange($event)"
      (reachEnd)="onSlideEnd($event)"
      class="mySwiper"
    >
      <ng-template swiperSlide *ngFor="let img of slides">
        <img class="swiper-slide1" data-src="{{ img }}" />
        <!-- <div class="swiper-lazy-preloader"></div> -->
      </ng-template>
    </swiper>
  </div>

  <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
</div>
```

and I'm trying to update the slider by adding new slides after the last slide is reached but the method `appendSlides()` is not updating the slider.

I also tried to update the `slides` array

```
appendSlides() {
    this.slides.push('https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-8.jpg')
}
```

But it is not working. Can someone please point me in the right direction?

I'm following the documentation provided here:

1. https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#virtual-slides
2. https://swiperjs.com/angular#virtual-slides
3. https://swiperjs.com/demos#virtual-slides

Here is the Stackblitz URL:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-52d8kq?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Is swiper.js is compatible with angular? Or its pure js library ?

Comment: @GaurangDhorda As per their documentation it is compatible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should replace the `slides` array rather than push another entry. Like this:

```
constructor(private cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}

appendSlides() {
    this.slides = [...this.slides, 'https://swiperjs.com/demos/images/nature-2.jpg'];
    this.cd.detectChanges();
}
```

Replacing the array completely will cause change detection to fire.

Comment: I tried it, but it does not work. I have added the Stackblitz URL in question

Comment: I got this to work, but I had to add `ChangeDetectorRef` to get it to work. See above.

Comment: @Richards Thank you for your help. It is working now ;)

Answer (score 1):

Demo in this [StackBlitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gkkbkj).

You have Two ways working First way is as suggested by R.Richards. And second way is using `template-ref`. First You need to declare template ref to html like this

```
<swiper #swiperRef [config]="swiper" (slideChange)="onSlideChange($event)" (reachEnd)="onSlideEnd($event)"
  class="mySwiper">
  <ng-template #slidesArray swiperSlide *ngFor="let img of slides">
    <img class="swiper-slide1" data-src="{{ img }}" />
  </ng-template>
</swiper>
```

Above, code `#swipeRef` is template reference variable, Now, You can acess it with component using @ViewChild() like below code..

```
@ViewChild('swiperRef') sliderRef?: SwiperComponent;
```

Now, when slide reach at end you need to call `appendSlide()` method of swiper js using this sliderRef variable. code shown below..

```
  onSlideEnd(event: any) {
this.sliderRef.swiperRef.appendSlide([
  `<div class="swiper-slide"><img class="swiper-slide1" src="${
    this.slides[0]
  }" /></div>`
]);
}
```

Now, You can see its working and adding new slides to at end.